# Como configurar Zona Horario en MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Como se puede realizar configuración de la zona horaria para mongodb, al realizar un insert en mongo con new Date(), me registra 5 horas adicionales. por ejemplo:

> db.publication.insert({_id:1,fecha:new Date()});
>   WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
>   db.publication.findOne(_id:1)
>   2016-10-19T14:08:22.156-0500 SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
>   db.publication.findOne({_id:1})
>   { "_id" : 1, "fecha" : ISODate("2016-10-19T19:08:14.027Z") }

Considero realizar un método para configurar esta hora a mi hora local, en este caso -5 horas para Colombia, pero si es posible hacer modificación al  servidor de mongodb preferiria hacer esto, pero no tengo conocimiento si se puede hacer.

Comment: se puede evidenciar en la linea 2* que la hora de log del error al consultar de forma incorrecta arroja la hora actual de mi equipo 14:08 2016-10-19T14:08:22.156-0500 SyntaxError: Unexpected token : pero en la linea 3* de resultante a la consulta se ve que el registro dice 19:08.

Answer (score 3):

MongoDB por defecto guarda todas las fechas en UTC. No hay forma de guardar fechas en una zona horaria distinta; sin embargo, se puede ocupar `getTimezoneOffset()` de `Date` para obtener la diferencia y manejar las zonas horarias desde la aplicación, así:

```
var fecha = new Date();
db.publication.save( { date: fecha,
                       offset: fecha.getTimezoneOffset() } );
```

Esto guardará un documento en MongoDB como el siguiente:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5807fc6fe820a6d1afe44fda"), "fecha" : ISODate("2016-10-19T23:05:55.336Z"), "offset" : 360 }
```

Ahora, ya que tenemos el offset, podemos restárselo a la fecha para obtener la fecha/hora original:

```
var documento = db.publication.findOne();
var fechaOriginal = new Date( documento.fecha.getTime() -  ( documento.offset * 60000 ) );
```

`fechaOriginal` tendrá la fecha desde la zona horaria que se realizó la operación.

Comment: Ok Luis Diego probare tu solución, ya que habia visto algo muy parecido a lo de la politica de zona horaria de mongo. Gracias.

Comment: para sorpresa mongodb registra las fechas con un diferencia de 5horas con respecto a mi hora local (colombia), pero a la hora de consultar la informacion para mi aplicacion, las fechas son ajustadas de nuevo a mi zona horaria, es decir, me evite hacer metodos adicionales para configurar esta informacion. Gracias.

Comment: Lo hace con una diferencia de 5 horas porque lo guarda en UTC; Colombia se encuentra en la zona horaria UTC-5.

Answer (score 0):

```
new Date( new Date().getTime() -  ( new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000 ) )
```

**Esto puede ayudar**

Comment: Considera leer [answer]

Comment: Hola Juan Eduardo, esta respuesta ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido. Las publicaciones que son básicamente código sin ninguna explicación no suelen ser de ayuda para otros usuarios. Por favor, edita tu respuesta para añadir una descripción de lo que hace y cómo soluciona el problema. Lee [answer] y completa el [tour] para más información (y con ello ganarás tu primera medalla en el sitio).

Answer (score 0):

Ajustando la respuesta que han dado, en mi caso estoy trabajando con mongodb, con una aplicacion hecha en nodejs y expressjs copn MVC

en el modelo en donde especifico el campo fecha lo tengo de la siguiente manera:

```js
fecha: {
  type: Date,
  default: new Date(new Date().getTime() - (new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000))
},
```

de esta manera aplicando el ejemplo de la respuesta anterior funciona y guarda en el formato que buscaba